# How to get a stored procedure scalar output and add it to each row in the pipeline?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on an SSIS package to transfer data from an ERP system (*Microsoft Dynamics AX*) to a custom CRM solution.  One of the things I need to transfer/update is customers.  In the CRM system, there is a field  called CustomerID that is unique to the CRM environment and must be set when the data is transferred from the ERP system to the CRM system.

The issue is that I must call a stored procedure to get the CustomerID for the next customer to be inserted.  How can I do this from within SSIS?  I am currently using a Data Flow to transfer data and the only place I can see to called the stored procedure is from within the ADO NET Source task as a SQL Command query and each time the procedure is called it increments the ID so every time the SSIS package is run it updates the CustomerID field for all customers in the CRM database.

The stored procedure resides on the custom CRM application. The stored procedure does not accept any input parameters. It simply outputs a scalar value like `CT000001`, `CT000002`, etc. every time it is called.

What are my other options for doing this properly?

Comment: Does CRM translate to MS Dynamics?

Comment: @billinkc No it does not.  It is not Dynamics CRM.

Comment: @Siva - The ERP is Microsoft Dynamics AX and the CRM is a custom built in house one.

Comment: @Siva - Yes on the CRM side.  The stored proc updates a table holding the latest customer number, and returns the value.  Usually, the number is something like CT000001, CT000002, etc

Comment: @Siva It doesn't need an input parameter.  The output is CT000001, CT000002, etc.

Comment: At my last gig, the approach I saw used was basically OLE DB Source to Script Destination. They had to call a webservice go generate those IDs and then another web service to insert the data. It was slow and painful. Something that can help is to use install [Balanced Data Distributor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30147) That allows the Engine to split the data flows out based on back pressure from the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the stored procedure for each row using Script Component and add the value to the pipeline downstream to the destination.

#### Sample SSIS 2012 package that illustrates a sample:

The sample uses the following database objects.

- SQL Server 2012 database named PracticeDB. In this scenario both the CRM and ERP tables are in the same database to keep it simple.
- Table *`dbo.CRM`* will contain the destination CRM data.
- Table *`dbo.ERP`* holds the source ERP data
- Table *`dbo.CustomerId`* is a hypothetical table that is in CRM system which will be used to increment the customer number.
- Stored procedure *`dbo.GetCustomerId`* increments the customer number whenever it is called.

#### Script to create the above mentioned database objects:

Below script will create the above mentioned objects and will insert some rows into the source ERP table.

```
USE PracticeDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.CRM(
    CRMId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerId int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(50) NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ERP(
    ERPId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerId(
    Id int NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomerId 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM dbo.CustomerId)
        INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerId (Id) VALUES(1);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerId (Id)
            SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.CustomerId;

    SELECT MAX(Id) AS CustomerId FROM dbo.CustomerId;   
END;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ERP (CustomerName) VALUES
        ('John Doe')
    ,   ('Jane Doe')
    ,   ('Stephen Smith')
    ,   ('Dean Jones')
    ;
GO
```

- Create an SSIS package and create an ADO.NET connection manager to connect to the appropriate data sources.
- Drag and drop a Data Flow Task onto the Control Flow tab
- Within the data flow task, drag and drop the components `ADO.NET Source`, `Script Component (Transformation)` and ADO.NET Destination.
- *ADO.NET Source* will read data from table *dbo.ERP*
- *ADO.NET Destination* will insert data into table *dbo.CRM*

Script Component will involve the following configuration.

- Double-click the Script Component to open the Script Component Editor.
- Click `Connection Managers` tab page
- Select the ADO.NET Connection Manager `ADONET_PracticeDB` and give it a name like **`PracticeDB`**. This connection manager will be used inside the script component code.

[image: Connection Managers]

- Click `Inputs and Outputs` tab page
- Rename *Input* to **`ERP`** and *Output* to **`CRM`**
- Expand CRM, select Output Columns and click *`Add Column`*.
- Rename the column name to CustomerID. The example uses the column of type integer. You need to change the data type according to your needs.
- Click `Script` tab page.

[image: Script Component]

- On the script tab page, click `Edit Script...`.
- Type the code shown in the below script component section. The script initiates the connection using the ADO.NET Connection Manager available on the package and then initiates the command object within the *`PreExecute`* method.
- The stored procedure is then called within the *`ERP_ProcessInputRow`* method for every row in the pipeline to generate new customer ids.

#### Script component code in C#

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    IDTSConnectionManager100 manager;
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        manager = base.Connections.PracticeDB;

        connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection = (SqlConnection)manager.AcquireConnection(null);

        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "dbo.GetCustomerId";
        
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }

    public override void ERP_ProcessInputRow(ERPBuffer Row)
    {
        Row.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

[image: Script component using C#]

- Close the Script component
- Executed the below query against data to check the rows before executing the package.

#### Table select queries:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ERP;
SELECT * FROM dbo.CRM;
SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomerId;
```

[image: Before execution]

After first execution of the package, you can notice that 4 rows have been inserted and also the stored procedure was successfully called to add the customer Ids.

[image: Execution 1]

After second execution of the package, you can notice that 4 more rows have been inserted and the stored procedure has successfully incremented the customer Ids.

[image: Execution 2]

Hope that gives you an idea.